# confusion while creating controller in Code igniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

**I'm Just confused while creating controller in code igniter.**

I have two main modules in my project.

1. menu in header section.
2. contact us form.

for menu i have created one controller naming devot in devot class i have called all the views for menu, now for contact us form i should go with same controller or i should create new controller.

I'm bit of confused on selection of controllers, how many controller should be there in one application. With only one controller can we complete one application  is that possible. ???????????

Comment: It is possible to create complete application using single controller. If your application is small e.g having 3-4 modules then you can use one controller.
But if there are so many modules and that pointing to different functionalities you can use different controllers.In your case one controller is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
class SampleController xtends CI_Controlle{
  public functin index(){
   $this->load->view('header.php');
   $this->load->view('yourpage.php');
  }

  public function page1(){
     $this->load->view('header.php');
     $this->load->view('yourpage1.php');
  }
}
```

codeigniter Read the Manual
[refer](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html)